# Check strings and add new column in SQL

Tags: sql, select, contains

I'm looking for a code that checks whether or not it's an animal.

My table looks like this:

| id | test |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fish_test |
| 1 | shoe |
| 1 | tiger_test |
| 1 | shirt |
| 1 | test_bird |

What I want to get is this table:

| id | test | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fish_test | 1 |
| 1 | shoe | 0 |
| 1 | tiger_test | 1 |
| 1 | shirt | 0 |
| 1 | test_bird | 1 |

So if the the column `test` contains the string `test`, it should set the new column to 1, else to 0.

How would this could or *If* condition look like in the select statement?

Comment: If your `id` column doesn't actually uniquely identify a row, it shouldn't be called `id`....

Comment: BTW, SQL does not contain any functionality for differentiating between inanimate objects and animals, - so how do you plan to do that part?

Comment: String-Manipulation has heavy differences between DBMS. So please tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Starting simple - `case when <column> like '%test%' then <something> else <something else> end`

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression:

```sql
SELECT mytable.*, CASE WHEN test LIKE '%test%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Note that the above syntax isn't valid ANSI/ISO SQL. Qualify the star to make it portable.

Comment: @jarlh good point, thanks for noticing